# Selecting a sheet with a dynamic name which contains a date

Tags: excel, vba, date, dynamic

I have been trying to select one of the sheets called "SYS 6.10.2020".  However, this sheet changes its date every week. Is there a VBA code that code could select the sheet based on today's date?

Comment: Maybe reference it usually the index number? Like worksheets(1) https://trumpexcel.com/vba-worksheets/

Comment: If your newest worksheet is placed at the end(right) of all the other worksheets, then you could use `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Worksheet Name

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' If it is the only worksheet that starts with "SYS ", "sys "...
Sub PartialMatch()
        
    Const wsName As String = "SYS "
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If StrComp(Left(ws.Name, Len(wsName)), wsName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        'MsgBox "Worksheet starting with '" & wsName _
             & "' not found.", vbCritical, "Fail"
        Debug.Print "Worksheet starting with '" & wsName & "' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Continue with code...
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    
End Sub
        
Sub ExactMatch()
        
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim wsName As String
    wsName = "SYS " & Replace(Format(Date, "d/m/yyyy"), "/", ".")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        'MsgBox "Worksheet '" & wsName & "' not found.", vbCritical, "Fail"
        Debug.Print "Worksheet '" & wsName & "' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Continue with code...
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Static String

You can do it by supplying the date (formatted in the appropriate format) to the `Sheets` function.

Quick Sample:

```
Sheets("SYS 6.10.2020").Select
```

### Dynamic String

```
 Sub Task1()

Dim myDate
myDate = Date
   
   MsgBox myDate
   
Dim LValue As String
 LValue = "SYS " & Format(myDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")

MsgBox LValue


 Sheets(LValue).Activate

End Sub
```

If there is only one sheet added per week, you could use the calendar within vba to find the last date (e.g. last monday) and generate the name from that.